# number picker in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two number pickers which one of them is under the other one but i need to make them side by side but i couldnt succeed. Also the number pickers are somehow connected. when i press up both of them moves up. Its probably because of calling the class spinner on click function, but i have no clue how can i do them separated without writing function for each one.

```
         $('<br/>').appendTo(tabPage); 
         $('<br/>').appendTo(tabPage); 
        var tableSpinnerRow = $('<div class="row"/>').appendTo(tabPage);
        var spinnerContainer = $('<div class=" container col-xs-12 "/>').appendTo(tableSpinnerRow);
        var spinner1 = $('<div class=" input-group spinner col-xs-2"/>').appendTo(spinnerContainer);
        var input1 = $('<input type="text" class="form-control  " value="1"/>').appendTo(spinner1);
        var input_Group1 = $('<div class="input-group-btn-vertical"/>').appendTo(spinner1);
        var buttonPlus1 = $('<button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>').appendTo(input_Group1);
        var buttonMinus1 = $('<button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>').appendTo(input_Group1);
        $('<br/>').appendTo(tabPage); 
        var spinnerContainer2 = $('<div class=" container col-xs-12"/>').appendTo(tableSpinnerRow);
        var spinner2 = $('<div class=" input-group spinner col-xs-2"/>').appendTo(spinnerContainer2);
        var input2 = $('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="1"/>').appendTo(spinner2);
        var input_Group2 = $('<div class="input-group-btn-vertical"/>').appendTo(spinner2);
        var buttonPlus2 = $('<button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i></button>').appendTo(input_Group2);
        var buttonMinus2 = $('<button class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></button>').appendTo(input_Group2);


     (function ($) {
    $('.spinner .btn:first-of-type').on('click', function() {

    $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) + 1);

  });
    $('.spinner .btn:last-of-type').on('click', function() {

    $('.spinner input').val( parseInt($('.spinner input').val(), 10) - 1);

  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its pretty hard to provide feedback on your alignment issue without a fiddle, link to your page, or css....

However this is how I would separate the two spinner click handlers without having to write separate functions for them.

```
$('.spinner').click(function(){
    $(this).val( parseInt($(this).find('input').val(), 10) + 1);
    $(this).slideUp();
});
```